# Is there a way to apply css style to group of elements working like (text-overflow: ellipsis) in text?

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I have a couple of elements inside div like this

```
                            <div class="progress-titles-wrapper">
                                <a href="#" class="progress-title">Earned</a>
                                <a href="#" class="progress-title">Sick</a>
                                <a href="#" class="progress-title">Annual</a>
                                <a href="#" class="progress-title">Earned</a>
                                <a href="#" class="progress-title">Sick</a>
                                <a href="#" class="progress-title">Annual</a>
                                <a href="#" class="progress-title">Earned</a>
                                <a href="#" class="progress-title">Sick</a>
                                <a href="#" class="progress-title">Annual</a>
                                <a href="#" class="progress-title">Earned</a>
                                <a href="#" class="progress-title">Sick</a>
                                <a href="#" class="progress-title">Annual</a>
                                <div class="seeMore d-flex align-items-center">
                                    <a href="#">See More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I want to show some of them depend on screen width and the remaining will (overflow: hidden) and put 3 Dots ... and show last one (See More) to open popup that contains all of progress-title divs.

My Css:

```
.progress-titles-wrapper{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:calc(100% - 200px);
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

I want final code show this
[image]

here is the live demo https://jsfiddle.net/yousefsalama14/2ur9w4jo/1/

Comment: elipsis work on text and not of div structures.. you can attain this with javacsript and not only with css

Answer (score 0):

it's not perfect at all but i have a possible solution for you:
In my example your list is scrollable over >1000px screen width, under that you  have your button with leading dots.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.progress-titles-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-titles-wrapper .progress-title {
  background-color: #296dac1a;
  border: 1px solid #296dac3b;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: #333;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.seeMore {
  background-color: #296dac1a;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #296dac3b;
  align-items: center;
  color: #337ab7;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}

.seeMore::before {
  content: '...';
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -24px;
  bottom: -10px;
}


.progress-titles {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: var(--titles-spacer);
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .progress-titles {
    --titles-spacer: 135px;
    width: calc(100% - var(--titles-spacer));
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: var(--titles-spacer);
  }

  .seeMore {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-titles-wrapper">
  <div class="progress-titles">
    <a href="#" class="progress-title">Earned</a>
    <a href="#" class="progress-title">Sick</a>
    <a href="#" class="progress-title">Annual</a>
    <a href="#" class="progress-title">Earned</a>
    <a href="#" class="progress-title">Sick</a>
    <a href="#" class="progress-title">Annual</a>
    <a href="#" class="progress-title">Earned</a>
    <a href="#" class="progress-title">Sick</a>
    <a href="#" class="progress-title">Annual</a>
    <a href="#" class="progress-title">Earned</a>
    <a href="#" class="progress-title">Sick</a>
    <a href="#" class="progress-title">Annual</a>
  </div>

  <div class="seeMore d-flex align-items-center">
    <a href="#">See More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```